# Linker cannot find .so file

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

I am building an executable and a `.so` file using another `.so`

```
mylib.so: mylib.o
     ld -shared -o mylib.so packer.o mylib.o -ldl -L../lib -lcustombuild
server: server.o packer.o
     gcc packer.o server.o -o server -L../lib -lcustombuild
```

The file `libcustombuild` is in dir lib one level above current dir (i.e. ../lib)
When I run my `./server` it throws error: `error while loading shared libraries: libcustombuild.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
I am sure the .so file is in right directory. 
`ls ../lib` output:  `libcustombuild.so`

Comment: `-L` provides a folder for the linker to look in for libraries while linking. It cannot help with loading an so at runtime. the so needs to be in the path somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is how I fixed it:

```
mylib.so: mylib.o
     ld -shared -o mylib.so packer.o mylib.o -ldl -L../lib -lcustombuild
server: server.o packer.o
     gcc packer.o server.o -o server -L../lib -lcustombuild
```

and

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib
```

`-Wl,-rpath` wasn't a valid command for ld

Answer (score 2):

-L only tells the linker where to find the link-time library. The .so file still needs to be known to the run-time library loader.

So you either need to use something like the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, or the `rpath` linker options, to tell the loader where to find your .so file, or put the .so file into one of the system library paths.

See [rpath - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the line to: `ld -shared -o mylib.so packer.o mylib.o -ldl -L../lib -lcustombuild -Wl,-rpath=../lib` and now I get this error: `unrecognized option '-Wl,-rpath=../lib'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `-Wl,-rpath` is not a valid command for ld. In fact it is an option for gcc/g++ as a linker option. `-Wl` means pass the parameter after the comma to the linker when calls it.

And, since rpath indicates to hard-code the path to the binary file, I think it is not a good idea to use relative path.